# What is the best way to get a sorted list (of finite length) from a large set of input

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

So let's say I have 100 million `Comparable`'s as streaming input and I want to output the top 100 of that input (in order--which is trivial I figure if you can find the top 100).  I'm assuming that some sort of insertion sort would be best, but what is the best way to accomplish that (if it is even the best way)?

The constraints are that you definitely see each object, one at a time (and I definitely *cannot* put the entire set into memory).

I was thinking of two possible solutions:

1) A simple linked list.  So as the first 100 objects come in they will be sorted (takes O(n) time--but n = 100).  Then as each successive object comes in, it will be inserted correctly (again O(n), n = 100, time), and if inserted, it will kick out the tail (otherwise the linked list will be unchanged if it's above the maximum value).

2) Use a heap.  I figure I can keep a heap, insert into the heap, then discard the root node (the top of the heap) if the size of the heap is above my maximum number of elements (100 in my case).  This should mean O(lg(n)) runtime, right?  Since both the insertion of an element and deletion of the root is O(lg(n)), right?

Are there any good libraries for a heap in Java?  I really don't want to have to code my own heap structure.

p.s.

If you're wondering why I'm doing this, it's for fantasy football purposes.  I have a program which finds the maximum projected points of a set of players under the constraint of a salaray cap (it's a brute force algorithm).  In fact that's another question entirely, which is how to solve a knapsack problem where you *must* have a set number of different types of items (i.e. 1 QB, 3 WRs, 2 RBs, 1 TE, 1 K, and 1 Defense).

So I have a large set (1,234) of teams which give a minimum projected amount of points, but now I'm trying to find groups of teams which have a wide range of different players.  I figure that a group of three teams is reasonable to solve (via brute force): 1,234 choose 3 = 312,419,184 (which, by my calculations will take about an hour and a half to process).  I calculate a group of teams' variance as the number of a times a player appears in each team (so the lower the value, the higher the group of teams' variance).

Comment: Use a `TreeSet` to store just the top 100?

Comment: @DavidWallace Thanks, I think that's exactly what I'm looking for (in terms of a heap implementation).  I would just need to sort the items correctly (which means implementing the `compareTo` method appropriately).

Comment: If your 100 is a constant (and it seems like that), in big O terms it doesn't matter what you do, you algorithm is always `O(n)` with `n` the size of the input. I don't think that the difference in performance between a heap and an array (using insertion sort) will be that huge for only 100 elements. You could simply try both and measure.

Comment: @VincentvanderWeele Since I asked the question, I should time them and get back to you--although you are probably correct...the only problem being that an insertion sort requires a lot more work (on my part) than using the `TreeSet` class.

Comment: If using a `TreeSet` is least effort: definitely go for that!

Comment: This is extraneous, but do any of you guys know of algorithms for solving the knapsack problem as I described.  I have seen the canonical 0-1 knapsack problem: where you take 0 or 1 of each item, but I haven't really found algorithms (or even a description) of the problem where you _must_ take certain types of items (and a specified number of each type).

Comment: @Jared You are right, that is definitely a different question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you are doing is adding, you can use this.

```
public static <T> SortedSet<T> topValues(final int n, final Comparator<T> comparator) {
    return new TreeSet<T>(comparator) {
        @Override
        public boolean add(T t) {
            // if less than N in size, just try to add it.
            if (super.size() < n)
                return super.add(t);

            T first = super.first();
            // if smaller than the first, discard it.
            if (comparator.compare(t, first) <= 0)
                return false;
            // otherwise try to add it.
            super.remove(first);
            super.add(t);
            return true;
        }
    };
}
```

or if the type is already Comparable

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> SortedSet<T> topValues(final int n) {
    return new TreeSet<T>() {
        @Override
        public boolean add(T t) {
            // if less than N in size, just try to add it.
            if (super.size() < n)
                return super.add(t);

            T first = super.first();
            // if smaller than the first, discard it.
            if (t.compareTo(first) <= 0)
                return false;
            // otherwise try to add it.
            super.remove(first);
            super.add(t);
            return true;
        }
    };
}
```

Just add all the values to this set and it will only have `n` values, discarding the smallest one each time.